# “Message Not Sent” notifications for days

Tags: sms, notifications

I replied to an SMS but my message couldn't be delivered. I presume because the originating number wasn't a mobile number but the fixed line on the sender.

Now I'm getting that notification in the notification bar every 10 minutes or so. How can I get rid of it ?

> "Message not sent - Touch to review the message and try again".

When I touch the notification, it opens the SMS app, with the threads list.

I deleted the message thread, tried to clear the cache, restarted the phone...

This was more than one week ago. I waited for the SMSC to give up trying to resend the message (after 3 days I believe). This is not a setting a network issue since I'm able to exchange SMS with other parties without problem.

It's the Android Messaging application version 4.4.4-37.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed another SMS application ([Handcent next SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.app.nextsms&hl=fr) not to name it) and could access and delete the pending message (in Delivery Report / Undelivered).